# Diodon not working after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: clipboard

After upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 Diodon doesn't grab selected text from Chrome or Opera. It does from Firefox and from terminal window or file manager. I need that to work as before.

Comment: Purge and Reinstall - if possible.

Comment: No help. CTRL+C works. Selecting text doesn't work. It used to work before upgrade do 22.04.

Comment: I wish I had an answer already, same problem after upgrade: Diodon sometimes works, sometimes it does not, which is highly frustrating. I also noticed that clipboard items appear in Zeitgeist journal. Which is very wrong, as far as I know!